# Usar filter con una propiedad del models django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Un saludo para todos.

Quiero poder filtrar los objetos de mi modelo según la edad calculada en una propiedad.

A continuación el modelo que estoy usando.

```
class Beneficiario(models.Model):
    fecha_nacimeinto = models.DateField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('fecha de nacimiento')
    )

    @property
    def edad(self):
        return self.calcular_edad(self.fecha_nacimeinto)
```

La intención es filtrar los objetos que coincidan con el campo edad del siguiente modelo.

```
class Racion(models.Model):
    """
    Este modelo define la ración establecida para cada beneficiario por edad
    """
    edad = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('edad'),
        help_text='Edad en años'
    )
    tipo_beneficiario = models.ForeignKey(
        TipoBeneficiario,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('tipo debeneficiario'),
        related_name='racion_tipo_beneficiario',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    producto = models.ForeignKey(
        Producto,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('producto'),
        related_name='racion_producto',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('cantidad'),
    )
```

Mi consulta seria algo como lo siguiente.

```
edad_racion = Racion.objects.filter(pk=1).first().edad
if edad_racion:
    beneficiarios = Beneficiario.objects.filter(edad=edad_racion)
```

Si alguien sabe como puedo obtener estos resultados, le agradezco la ayuda que me pueda brindar.

Comment: cambia la primera consulta de filter por get `Racion.objects.get(pk=1)` como lo tienes es ms lento

Comment: hice tu consulta y me funciono, aun no comprendo lo que preguntas

Answer (score 2):

Una forma elegante de resolver esto que tal si cambias tu modelo  de **`Beneficiario`** a :

```
class Beneficiario(models.Model):
    fecha_nacimeinto = models.DateField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('fecha de nacimiento')
    )
    @property
    def edad(self):
        return self.calcular_edad(self.fecha_nacimeinto)

    def racion(self):
        return Racion.objects.get(edad=self.edad)
```

Con esto Simulamos la relacion entre Tablas, y puedes hacer:

```
b = Beneficiario.objects.get()
b.racion().cantidad
```

Lo importante es garantizar que el método `calcular_edad` este devolviendo un valor numérico valido para la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Te paso a comentar, no se puede usar directamente una propiedad como si fuera un atributo puesto que Django utiliza solo consultas SQL para obtener los datos.

Podes utilizar una lista de comprensión para esto:

```
[objeto for objeto in Beneficiario.objects.all() if objeto.edad == edad_racion]
```

Acabo de probar esto y funciona perfectamente.
Saludos